# If cell in column A:A is highlighted, highlight the cell adjacent to that cell in the next column

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to highlight the cell directly beside a cell in column B if its adjacent cell is highlighted. Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub test_highlight()

Dim highlight As Range
Dim range1 As Range
Set range1 = Columns("A:A")

For Each highlight In range1
    If highlight.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow Then
    highlight.Offset(, 1).Cells.Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbYellow

End If
Next highlight

End Sub
```

Comment: Are the cells highlighted with conditional formatting? Or is their interior color *exactly* yellow and not some shade of it?

Comment: If it is Conditional formatting, just include the next column in the applies to.

Comment: It's exactly vbYellow from a report where it is already highlighted. I use text to columns for separating first and last names in my script and it removes the highlighting from the cell when it is transferred to the next column. So, I am trying to highlight it with the corresponding name.